# Extending Date prototype - can this ever be null?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to extend the Date prototype in JavaScript like this:

```
Date.prototype.toLastDayOfPreviousMonth = function() {
    return new Date(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth(), 0);
}
```

However I'm not sure if I can ever expect `this` to be null here. My thinking is that if someone ever wants to do something like this:

```
var dateA = null;
dateA.toLastDayOfPreviousMonth();
```

The above function won't ever get called - because we're calling this on null and not Date. I'm not interested in quirks like calling the function through apply etc. Just 'genuine' usage `date.toLastDayOfPreviousmonth();`

One of the similar extensions I found had this check:

`var obj = this instanceof Date ? this : null;` Does it have any sense at all?

Comment: If you are interested only in "genuine usage", that is defined as calling your method only on date objects, then no your `this` will never be `null`. You don't need to do anything special about it, you even want your method to throw an exception when it's `null` anyway.

Comment: Yes, exactly. If anyone is trying to do something weird here I want the method to throw.

Comment: Better to leave a guard like I have shown in my answer and be done with it. Instead of extending the `Date`, why can't this be a util function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in sloppy mode. In that mode, the `this` value must always be an object. If you pass a `null` or `undefined` primitive, the `this` value end up being the global object.

However, strict mode allows arbitrary values. Then yes, `this` can be `null`.

```
"use strict";
Date.prototype.toLastDayOfPreviousMonth = function() {
  return this === null;
};
Date.prototype.toLastDayOfPreviousMonth.call(null); // true
```

If you don't want to consider ways of manually passing a custom `this` value (e.g. `call`, `apply`, `bind` or `Reflect`), then

- Either you are not calling the function as a method, in this case `this` will be the global object in sloppy mode and `undefined` in strict mode.
- Or you are calling the function as a method of some object. In this case, `this` will be that object. `null` is not an option because it's not an object.
- Or you are calling the function as a method of some primitive which can be wrapped in an object. In this case, `this` will be that object wrapper. `null` is not an option because it's not an object-wrappable.

Comment: Call and apply are always possible, but if someone does this then he should know what he is doing.

Comment: Thanks for this full answer. Especially the comparison between 'sloppy' and strict mode. I didn't know the difference is THAT huge.